# Is CryptoJS vulnerable to the OpenSSL Heartbleed bug?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, openssl, cryptojs, heartbleed-bug

We are using CryptoJS  in our application. Since CryptoJS  uses OpenSSL, are we vulnerable to the Heartbleed bug? If yes, what can we do to prevent it?

Comment: Consider asking on security.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Gareth Thanks.I have posted there as well.Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps security.stackexchange.com or crypto.stackexchange.com.

Comment: duplicate: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55711/is-crypto-js-vulnerable-to-heartbleed-attack

Answer (score 2):

> Since 'crypto.js' uses open SSL ,are we vulnerable to heartbleeding attack?

The [`heartbleed` attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed) is connected to "*handling of the Transport Layer Security (TLS) heartbeat extension*".

So,  heartbleed attack is possible only if `crypto.js` has TLS / SSL server or client; and you are using its as TLS / SSL server or client.

If you don't use TLS from it, (or if the library has no tls/ssl client as it looks like to be - can't find TLS in [sources](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/source/browse/tags/3.1.2/src)) - you are not vulnerable  to  `heartbleed`.

> If yes,what can we do to prevent it?

Update your system's OpenSSL library; Check the servers and clients which are connecting to you for heartbleed  vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.We have downloaded cryptoJS.js from the mentioned resource and it is included in our application package and site. Site is hosted on our server.Do we need to check for any other vulnerability?

Comment: user1533947, you should check the OpenSSL library installed on your server (and update it to the most recent version from this week). If you are using "`https://`" protocol, your web-server daemon (apache, nginx, etc) may be vulnerable to heartbleed.